# Writing differential equation as an integral one

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $$u'(x)x + v(x)=0.$$
Integrating with respect to $x$, we get $$u(y)y-\int_0^yu(x)dx +\int_0^yv(x)dx= 0.$$
Is there a similar technique for functionals $U, V$, defined on some functional space, and satisfy $$DU(x)[Lx]+ V(x)= 0,$$
where $L$ is some linear operator?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: What does $D$ denote? The functional derivative? Also, do you have some application in mind, where the functionals have a specific form?

Comment: Yes this is the functional derivative (Frechet or Gâteaux one).